# how do i get the updateprofile in firebase to work?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to have users add a displayname when they create their ID.

I have it setup up for the user to make their id on the first screen, and then when you hit next it creates the ID, then it goes to the update profile page to update the display name.

I got everything to work but when I introduced the second update page it crashes when I get directed to that page.

signup page

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest;

public class signup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    //defining view objects
    private EditText editTextEmail;
    private EditText editTextPassword;
 //   private EditText editTextName;
    private Button buttonSignup;

    private TextView textViewSignin;

    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


    //defining firebaseauth object
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

        //initializing firebase auth object
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        //if getCurrentUser does not returns null
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
            //that means user is already logged in
            //so close this activity
            finish();

            //and open profile activity
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), profile.class));
        }

        //initializing views
        editTextEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
        editTextPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
        textViewSignin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewSignin);
      //  editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

        buttonSignup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignup);

        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

        //attaching listener to button
        buttonSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
        textViewSignin.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    private void registerUser(){

        //getting email and password from edit texts
        String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password  = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();

        //checking if email and passwords are empty
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Please enter password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        //if the email and password are not empty
        //displaying a progress dialog

        progressDialog.setMessage("Working Please Wait...");
        progressDialog.show();

        //creating a new user
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        //checking if success
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){

                            finish();

                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), secondsignup.class));
        //                    Toast.makeText(signup.this,"Registration Successful",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(signup.this,"Registration Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if(view == buttonSignup){
            registerUser();
        }

        if(view == textViewSignin){
            //open login activity when user taps on the already registered textview
            startActivity(new Intent(this, mainlogin.class));
        }

    }
}
```

secondsignup page

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.auth.UserProfileChangeRequest;



public class secondsignup extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText mUsername;
    private Button mUpdateProfileBtn;
    FirebaseUser mUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_secondsignup);

        mUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
        mUpdateProfileBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSignin);
        String username = user.getDisplayName();
        mUsername.setText(username);

        mUpdateProfileBtn.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    //       @Override
    //       public void onClick(View v) {
    private void updatename() {
        //updating user's profile data
        String nameUser = mUsername.getText().toString();
        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName(nameUser)
                .build();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(nameUser)) {
            mUsername.setError("Enter your Full Name");
        }

        //if the field is not null, process continue to update profile
        else {
            mUser.updateProfile(profileUpdate)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) { //success on updating user profile
                                Toast.makeText(secondsignup.this, "Registration Successful",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                startActivity(new Intent(secondsignup.this, MainActivity.class));
                            } else { //failed on updating user profile
                                Toast.makeText(secondsignup.this, "Registration Failed",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        if (view == mUpdateProfileBtn) {
            updatename();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Share your error log.

Comment: this is the crash report from firebase below

Comment: Exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick (AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5201)

Comment: please share you more error log.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `onClick()` method like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    if (view.getId == R.id.buttonSignin) {
        updatename();
    }
}
```

Comment: Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cookout.appserver.app/com.cookout.appserver.app.secondsignup}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2434)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)
thats what i got with the change

Comment: You forgot to add your `secondactivity` activity in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Please add your activity to your AndroidManifest.xml` file.